# How to remove special charaters in shortId

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) nodejs package to create IDs in my project, i wanted to know if it can an ID could be generated without a special character?

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation provided by the author on npm, you can set the characters you want to generate id with, but the total of characters should be 64.

```
shortid.characters('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$@');
```

[A-Z][a-z][0-9] gives a total of 62, you have to use 2 special characters for it to make it work.

> You must provide a string of all 64 unique characters. Order is not
>   important.-- npm shortid docs.

Its the way the package is created, and you have to provide 2 special characters.

Comment: I wonder what was in the mind of the author for enforcing 64 characters. LOL.